# AJAX: Solving error with 200 OK by removing 'dataType: 'json''

Tags: json, ajax, types

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862066/jquery-ajax-always-returns-error-data-being-added-to-database)
and the answer provided by @Musa.

I successfully got rid of the error message by removing the 'dataType:'json''. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-returns-200-ok-but-an-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success), it was because my return JSON was malformed.

However, I had exactly the same thing in another page and it worked just fine without removing 'dataType:'json''. The only difference is that one is inside a button and one is triggered by canvas draw event.

How does that even work?

## Case 1

JQuery: 3.2.1

This is called by draw(). I need to comment out 'dataType:'json'' for it to work.

```
function StoreData() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        begin_x: begin_x,
        begin_y: begin_y,
        end_x: end_x,
        end_y: end_y
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "StoreLine",
        type: "POST",
        //dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result.d);
            console.log("success in storeData.");
        },
        error: function (exception) {
            console.log("error in storeData.");
            alert(exception);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This is the DefaultController class for the previous code snippet.

```
    public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    String connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    private bool Insert(String connectionString, float begin_x, float begin_y, float end_x, float end_y)
    {
        var result = false;
        String commandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Lines (Chart_Id, begin_x, begin_y, end_x, end_y) VALUES(1, @beginX, @beginY, @endX, @endY)";

        List<SqlParameter> prm = new List<SqlParameter>()
        {
            new SqlParameter("@beginX", SqlDbType.Float) {Value = begin_x},
            new SqlParameter("@beginY", SqlDbType.Float) {Value = begin_y},
            new SqlParameter("@endX", SqlDbType.Float) {Value = end_x},
            new SqlParameter("@endY", SqlDbType.Float) {Value = end_y}
        };
        Int32 rows = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, commandText, CommandType.Text, prm.ToArray());
        if (rows > 0) result = true;

        return result;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string StoreLine(float begin_x, float begin_y, float end_x, float end_y)
    {
        if (Insert(connectionString, begin_x, begin_y, end_x, end_y)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

## Case 2

JQuery: 1.10.2

This is the function that works without removing 'dataType:'json''

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/calledmethodaspxpage.aspx/calledmethod",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ tripData: data }),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                            //do something before send
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.d) {
                            //do something
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                            //handle error
                    }
                });
```

}

Here's the code behind accompanying it.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool CalledMethod(TripData tripData)
    {
        //some procedures that work

        return (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.id));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, which version of jQuery are you using? It would also be useful if you add client side code and a server response with headers so others can reproduce your problem and give you the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: @pjc89 sure thing

Comment: Hi, can you add a server response example? ( headers and body ). The server side code is not really necessary to reproduce your issue, whats important is what jQuery gets in response.

Comment: If you do, make sure to remove any sensitive data