# ajax function not working with spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

This is my ajax function

```
$("#submitButtonNc").click(function(){
    var newCreditLimit=$('#newCreditLimit').val();
    var cardNumber=$('#selectedCard').val();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'updateSupplymentaryCreditLimit.json',
        dataType: "json",
        data : {
            'cardNumber' :cardNumber,
            'newCreditLimit':newCreditLimit
        },

        success : function(json) {
            alert("aassdd");

        },
        error:function(error){
            alert("error",error.toString());

        }
    });
```

This is my back end java function. I have used spring MVC:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "updateSupplymentaryCreditLimit", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody String  updateSupplymentaryCreditLimit(@RequestParam("cardNumber") String cardNumber,
        @RequestParam("newCreditLimit") String  newCreditLimit){
    String message =null;
    try{
        double creditLimit=Double.parseDouble(newCreditLimit);
        SupplementaryCreditCardLimitBean  supplementaryCreditCardLimitBean =new SupplementaryCreditCardLimitBean();
        supplementaryCreditCardLimitBean.setCardNumber(cardNumber);
        supplementaryCreditCardLimitBean.setNewCreditLimit(creditLimit);
        message= "Success";

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            message= "Error";

        }
    return message;
}
```

When I click `#submitButtonNc` button back end `updateSupplymentaryCreditLimit` function called but response display  in front end ajax function

```
error:function(error){
    alert("error",error.toString());
}
```

please tell me what is the reason display error alert

Comment: Is there any exception thrown while running the code in `updateSupplymentaryCreditLimit` method?

Comment: Please return the json type from your function, even try to map error also in JSON

Comment: No VPK. updateSupplymentaryCreditLimit function return "Success" String

Comment: So does the `error` function called after ajax complete? If yes, what was printed in `alert("error",error.toString());`?

Comment: VPK, It was printed this error "parsererror" "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: Possibility of null pointer exception, if `newCreditLimit` is null then `double creditLimit=Double.parseDouble(newCreditLimit);` will throw null pointer exception. Please confirm the exception by adding error in your alert string `message= "Error" + e.getMessage();`

Comment: I think the problem is with the `dataType : json` in the ajax request. As it might be expecting the json response from the server. As currently it might getting as plain string / HTML. I would recommend to remove the `dataType:json` and try again.

Comment: Sandeep Kokate ,But data values passed to the back end and updateSupplymentaryCreditLimit function return "Success" String

Comment: @jhone, could you try again by removing the `dataType:json` property of ajax request?

Comment: VPK , I have removed dataType:json but it isn't working

Comment: If you can add the external library, it could give the better solution. Try to add `org.json.JSONObject`.

Comment: Try these answers solutions from question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862066/jquery-ajax-always-returns-error-data-being-added-to-database/19418845

Comment: How about adding produces = "application/json" in @Requestmapping,